# chackra ui accordion open when page load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, accordion, chakra-ui

I try to create side menu and the accordion to open based on page URL, I developing using Nextjs. for now I got the index from 0 to 1 but accordion is not opening, each time user click on the menu will redirected them to another page, that is why I want it to read from URL.

```
export default function SideMenu() {
      const [accIndex, setaccIndex] = useState(0) // initially 0
      const router = useRouter();
      useEffect(() => {
        //remove /
        let url = router.pathname;
        let newUrl = url.slice(1, url.length); //remove / at the beginning
        let second = newUrl.search("/"); // search for any / in trail
        let cutUrl = second > -1 ? newUrl.slice(0, second) : newUrl;
        for (const x in Menu) {
          if (cutUrl === Menu[x].item.toLowerCase()) {
            setaccIndex(Menu[x].index); // set to 1
          }
        }
      }, []);
      
      function selectedMenu(path) {
        router.push(path);
      }
    return (
    <>
      <Accordion allowMultiple defaultIndex={[accIndex]}>
        {/* dashboard */}
        <AccordionItem>
          <AccordionButton
            className="my-box"
            onClick={() => selectedMenu("/dashboard")}
          >Dashboard
          </AccordionButton>
        </AccordionItem>
        {/* dashboard  end*/}

        {/* about */}
        <AccordionItem>
          <AccordionButton>
            about
            <AccordionIcon />
          </AccordionButton>
          <AccordionPanel>
            {/* company 1 */}
            <AccordionItem>
              <AccordionButton onClick={() => selectedMenu("/com/company1")}>
                company 1
              </AccordionButton>
            </AccordionItem>
            {/* company 1 end*/}
          </AccordionPanel>
        </AccordionItem>
     </Accordion>
     </>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `index` instead of default index. It doesn't make sense to have `allowMultiple` here, as that would mean you would have more than one accordion item open but only one will be reflected in the url.

You can use `useMemo` instead of the `useEffect`:

```
      const router = useRouter();
      const index = useMemo(() => {
        //remove /
        let url = router.pathname;
        let newUrl = url.slice(1, url.length); //remove / at the beginning
        let second = newUrl.search("/"); // search for any / in trail
        let cutUrl = second > -1 ? newUrl.slice(0, second) : newUrl;
        for (const x in Menu) {
          if (cutUrl === Menu[x].item.toLowerCase()) {
            return Menu[x].index; // set to 1
          }
        }
        return 0; //default return, could be something else
      }, []);
   
      ....

      
    return (
    <>
      <Accordion index={index}>
```